What weave/knit pattern is used in my glasses cloth?
Here are close-up images of my glasses cloth, front and back. I am curious to know what kind of weave or knit pattern is used in its construction. I speculate that it may be double stockinette knit, but I lack an experienced eye.
Whilst there's much information on the internet about the construction of larger microfibre towels and cloths, there is little about the 'silkier' type often used for cleaning lenses.



It's really hard to see, but both sides look like stockinette stitch. Usually you'd see stockinette (knit) stitches on the front and purl stitches on the back. Having stockinette on both sides indicates a double-knit, but you already suspected that, so not sure if this helps you. BTW you shouldn't confuse Microfiber with weave. Microfiber (as the name implies) is a type of fiber that can be woven or knit in different patterns.
